# RDB and RDF mapping - how to?

Tags: postgresql, rdf, graph-databases

I have 3 Relational DBs, I would like to map a graph database so we can manage ontologies and query across them, the databases must remain as RDBs and the RDF mapping should allow querying via SPARQL. While I understand the theory I'm struggling to find a walk through guide, and help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [R2RML](https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/).

Comment: Thankyou, since posting this I discovered R2RML and a few other tools, but I'm struggling to implement this, essentially the basics of how do you create a graph database to link to 3 databases for querying via SPARQL. A dummy guide would help me greatly.

Comment: There's software out there that will do that for you; you needn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Once I get some kind of tutorial I'll be fine, but its the first steps I'm stuck on. The last thing I want to do is reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This (http://www.stardog.com/blog/virtual-graphs-in-stardog-5/) is how we do it, ymmv with other systems.